# EKEventStoreChangedNotification not firing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, eventkit

So I'm currently playing around with EventKit and was trying to get the EKEventStoreChangedNotification to fire when I add/modify/delete calendar entries in the native Calendar app, but after asking permission to access the Calendar, confirming that I'm authorized and signing up for the notification with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(storeChanged:)
                                             name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

the selector is never called. Also tried the block syntax, which doesn't work either.

So I figured I'm doing something wrong and found this [sample code](https://github.com/vandadnp/ios-7-programming-cookbook-source-codes/blob/master/Chapter%2019/Handling%20Event%20Changed%20Notifications/Handling%20Event%20Changed%20Notifications/AppDelegate.m), which supposedly has working notifications, but even after pulling that project and making sure that the addObserver line is getting called, I haven't been able to see the selector being called when I modify the calendar.

Any ideas how to debug this further?

Comment: Are you trying in the simulator or on a device?

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa  Could you please specify where do you mentioned the above code and how you tested?

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa Also, could you paste the code of storeChanged: method. Is it has the notification object as a parameter?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your `EKEventStore` isn't being deallocated. For example, assign it to a strong property.

The following app logs a string when an edit is made in the stock Calendar app:

```
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder<UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) EKEventStore *eventStore;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(eventStoreChangedNotification:) name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification object:nil];
        }
    }];

    return YES;
}

- (void)eventStoreChangedNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Event store changed");
}

@end
```

Comment: Do not set the `object:` to `nil`. That will lead to you receiving spurious notifications for any other `EKEventStore` objects in your app. Set the object to `self.eventStore`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the eventStore as object. Check this example. Works for me.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(storeChanged:)
                                             name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification
                                           object:eventStore];
```

[Observing External Changes to the Calendar Database](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ObservingChanges/ObservingChanges.html)

Comment: It's not necessary. (That said, you *ought* to specify the object, or you'll get notified for every EKEventStore in the app which could become slow if there's more than one...)

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that `EKEventStore` object stays in memory for use.

These scenarios will **not work** with ARC:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) EKEventStore *eventStore;
self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

This scenarios will **work** with ARC:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) EKEventStore *eventStore;

self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(eventStoreChangedNotification:) name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification object:nil];
    }
}];
```

Comment: I am having the same issue and none of the above solutions have worked for me.

Comment: I am also having problems with this. Did this ever work for anyone in 10.9? I have tried the same code in 10.10 Yosemite and it works fine, but not in 10.9. @Ramshad did you find a work-around?

Comment: @ZS: Make sure your EKEventStore isn't being deallocated. That's the only trick. :)

Comment: Do not set the `object:` to `nil`. That will lead to you receiving spurious notifications for any other `EKEventStore` objects in your app. Set the object to `self.eventStore`.